# Adding a DataColumn to a DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How do I go about adding a `ButtonColumn` to a `DataTable`.

I am basically using a `DataTable` as the `DataSource` of a `DataGrid` and need to add a `ButtonColumn` to the `DataTable` so that when I `DataBind` it to the `DataGrid` it all works.

Although when I try

```
dt.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
```

This is not allowed. It has to be a basic `DataColumn`.

Thanks in advance, I know it's a simple question so shouldn't be hard to answer.

Comment: Just realised how stupid this question is, sorry, was having a moment!

Comment: Yeh, feel very silly when you read your own question and thing "who's asking this rubbish?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add a `ButtonColumn` to `DataTables`. Instead, you add the `ButtonColumn` to the `DataGrid` (front side or back side) and define its bind (with the `DataField` property) to a column in the `DataTable`.